# how not to affect \ref by hyperref

Tags: hyperref, ref, hyperlink

This script

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
We use this equation

\begin{equation}
  c=\frac{a}{b}
  \label{eq:frac}
\end{equation}

Equation \ref{eq:frac} can be seen in the homepage of an \href{www.oecd.org}{International Organisation}.
\end{document}
```

produces the output:

[image]

I would like hyperlinks to be created only for webpages, not Tables, Figures and Equations. How to achieve this when also using `\usepackage{hyperref}`?

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Non-clickable `\ref` links and clickable `\href`s? What about `\pageref`, `\url`, the toc etc.?

Comment: You can suppress the visual highlighting of the link if I remember correctly. Is that what you want? Or a non-hyperlink creating `\ref`?

Comment: Quoting from the `hyperref` manual: “For instances where you want a reference to use the correct counter, but not to create a link, there are starred forms”.  Try `\ref*` instead of `\ref` (but I’m not sure that this is what you want).

Comment: @GuM `\href*` seems to do the job

Comment: @Viesturs, now your question become completely unclear ...

Comment: If you don't want all the linking done by `hyperref` and just want to display the url, maybe the `url` package is what you are looking for?

Comment: Are you looking for the `hidelinks` option to `hyperref`?

Comment: @AndrewSwann I want hyperlinks to be created only for webpages, not Tables, Figures and Equations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the option

```
implicit=false
```

for `hyperref`:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[implicit=false]{hyperref}

\begin{document}
We use this equation

\begin{equation}
  c=\frac{a}{b}
  \label{eq:frac}
\end{equation}

Equation \ref{eq:frac} can be seen in the homepage of an \href{https://www.oecd.org}{International Organisation}.
\end{document}
```

Note you need a correct uri for the link to work.